# Run Laravel migrations on just one server (like ->onOneServer() for scheduled cronjobs)

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm running a Laravel app on multiple servers at the same time. It's running in a Docker image. Each time I deploy some code changes, Docker image is restarted and then it runs `after_deployment.sh` script which contains `php artisan migrate --force`. This script is executed by ALL of my servers, not just one.

All servers use the same central DB. So if two servers try to run the `php artisan migrate` at roughly the same time, only the first server succeeds, the other fails somewhere in the middle and logs an error. This is not great.

There was a similar problem with running cronjobs (Laravel Scheduler) on just one server, but that is now solved as Laravel provides the `->onOneServer();` method for Scheduled jobs.

Is there something similar for running migrations on just one server? Something like `php artisan migrate --force --on-one-server`?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [Laravel 9.38](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/44743), you have the `php artisan migrate --isolated` that will acquire an atomic lock before running the migrations.
From the [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#running-migrations):

> When the `isolated` option is provided, Laravel will acquire an atomic
> lock using your application's cache driver before attempting to run
> your migrations. All other attempts to run the `migrate` command while
> that lock is held will not execute; however, the command will still
> exit with a successful exit status code

Please note that you cache driver should be set to one of the following:
`memcached`, `redis`, `dynamodb`, `database`, `file`, or `array`